# What is a way to access .accdb files for reading and writing?

Tags: winforms, ms-access

I have an Microsoft Access Database (.accdb) that stores information needed in an application.

Is there a way to distribute my application with the access database without having the user have access installed or get the user to go and download and install the office runtime?

The windows form application that uses the access database is developed in VB.net in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: If you used an MDB instead of an ACCDB, you wouldn't need to install the ACE database engine, because Jet 4 is installed on all versions of Windows starting with 2000.

Comment: What version of .NET are you building this with and how are you distrubuting this app?

Answer (score 1):

An installation of Access is not needed. Your installation should include all the necessary files to interact with the accdb file.

Are you using something other than .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB?

Comment: no I was using OLE DB. but when I installed the application on a machine without office it would error out.  When I installed the runtime for office it would work fine.

Comment: If you used an MDB you wouldn't need to install the runtime.

Comment: But mdb files are older technology right?  What files/components need to be installed to use the .net framework data provider for OLE DB?